# How get rid of 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'Assembly' error?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm hoping someone can help me on this : because of the usage of System.Net.Http package, I'm not anymore able to load an embedded resource with `var assembly = GetType (MyClass).GetTypeInfo ().Assembly;`. I think this has something to do with the PCL associated profile which is "Profile78", no ? Do you have any idea to get around this problem ?

Thx in advance for your help ! =)

Comment: Is it build or runtime error?

Comment: I's a build error ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is some weirdness with GetTypeInfo based on whether it is IReflectableType or not. Does this code change resolve the issue without causing other issues?

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(MyClass).Assembly;
```